# How can I create a day-number for a 4-year cycle in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, cycle

I have timeseries data with datetimeindex, price and the cycle phase.
My dataframe looks like this:

| Dateindex | Price | CyclePhase | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1928-01-03 00:00:00 | 71.04 | 0 | 1 |
| 1928-01-04 00:00:00 | 70.88 | 0 | 2 |
| 1928-01-05 00:00:00 | 70.2 | 0 | 3 |
| 1928-01-06 00:00:00 | 70.64 | 0 | 4 |
| … | … | … | … |
| 1929-05-09 00:00:00 | 104.08 | 1 | 400 |
| 1929-05-10 00:00:00 | 105.36 | 1 | 401 |
| 1929-05-11 00:00:00 | 104.96 | 1 | 402 |
| 1929-05-13 00:00:00 | 102.56 | 1 | 403 |
| … | … | … | … |
| 1930-11-08 00:00:00 | 63.56 | 2 | 844 |
| 1930-11-10 00:00:00 | 62.16 | 2 | 845 |
| 1930-11-11 00:00:00 | 63.16 | 2 | 846 |
| … | … | … | … |
| 1931-12-29 00:00:00 | 31.84 | 3 | 1185 |
| 1931-12-30 00:00:00 | 32.4 | 3 | 1186 |
| 1931-12-31 00:00:00 | 32.48 | 3 | 1187 |
| 1932-01-02 00:00:00 | 31.28 | 0 | 1 |
| 1932-01-04 00:00:00 | 30.24 | 0 | 2 |
| 1932-01-05 00:00:00 | 30.2 | 0 | 3 |
| … | … | … | … |

I would like to create the column "Day" where it is counting up for each row in the dataframe until the cycle restarts. (when CyclePhase changes from 3 to 0 again).

How can I do that best in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create grouper to flag the rows where cycle changes the calculate cumcount to assign row numbers per group

```
s = df['CyclePhase'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
df['Day'] = s.groupby(s).cumcount() + 1
```

---

```
              Dateindex   Price  CyclePhase  Day
0   1928-01-03 00:00:00   71.04           0    1
1   1928-01-04 00:00:00   70.88           0    2
2   1928-01-05 00:00:00   70.20           0    3
3   1928-01-06 00:00:00   70.64           0    4
4   1929-05-09 00:00:00  104.08           1    5
5   1929-05-10 00:00:00  105.36           1    6
6   1929-05-11 00:00:00  104.96           1    7
7   1929-05-13 00:00:00  102.56           1    8
8   1930-11-08 00:00:00   63.56           2    9
9   1930-11-10 00:00:00   62.16           2   10
10  1930-11-11 00:00:00   63.16           2   11
11  1931-12-29 00:00:00   31.84           3   12
12  1931-12-30 00:00:00   32.40           3   13
13  1931-12-31 00:00:00   32.48           3   14
14  1932-01-02 00:00:00   31.28           0    1
15  1932-01-04 00:00:00   30.24           0    2
16  1932-01-05 00:00:00   30.20           0    3
```

Comment: do you happen to know how I could divide all prices by their Day 1 value for each cycle?

Comment: glad to help, its simple just transform with first: `df['New_Price'] = df['Price'] / df.groupby('Day')['Price'].transform('first')`

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby on the year like this:

```
df['Day'] = df.groupby(df['Dateindex'].dt.year // 4).cumcount().add(1)
```

If your data starts from some year that is not divisible by `4`, then you can do:

```
years = df['Dateindex'].dt.year
df['Day'] = df.groupby(years.sub(years.min()) // 4).cumcount().add(1)
```

**Note**: if your `Dateindex` is indeed the index, then

```
years = df.index.year
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  The first line works well. The version for the year not divisible by 4 brings an error "  AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'sub'  "

Comment: Oh, just replacae `sub` with normal `-` operation then.